# Export regression in R to Latex - decimal alignment

Tags: rstudio

I did regressions in R using the lm function. Afterwards, I want to export it to Latex with the following code.

```
#export to Latex
texreg(list(model_cont,model_mag,model_pos), 
       digits = 4,  
       stars = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
       custom.model.names = c("Delta", "Delta","Delta"),
       custom.coef.names = c("Intercept","FF","FG"),
       caption = "Contemporaneous regression results",
       label = "ContReg",
       caption.above = TRUE,
       siunitx = TRUE,
       booktabs = TRUE,
       use.packages = FALSE)
```

The Latex code from R is as follows:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Contemporaneous regression results}
\begin{center}
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false, table-text-alignment=right}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=4.7] S[table-format=4.6] S[table-format=4.7]}
\toprule
 & {Delta} & {Delta} & {Delta} \\
\midrule
Intercept       & 0.0001       & -0.0004^{*} & 0.0001        \\
                & (0.0001)     & (0.0002)    & (0.0001)      \\
FF              & 0.1234^{**}  & 0.4567^{*}  & -0.1237       \\
                & (0.3255)     & (0.2354)    & (0.2134)      \\
FG             & 0.1246^{***} & -0.6678     & 0.7788^{***}  \\
                & (0.1256)     & (0.3545)    & (0.4575)      \\
\midrule
R$^2$           & 0.5113       & 0.1150      & 0.5135        \\
Adj. R$^2$      & 0.4101       & 0.2124      & 0.9117        \\
Num. obs.       & 3888         & 3780        & 3394          \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.01$; $^{**}p<0.05$; $^{*}p<0.1$}}
\end{tabular}
\label{ContReg}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The resulting table in Latex aligns all decimals, also for the observations. However, I don't want to align the decimal of the Observations. Can someone advise please?

Comment: You can wrap them in curly brackets: `Num. obs. & {3888} & {3780} & {3394}\\ `.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to encasing the numbers in the `Num. obs.` row in curly braces, you may also want to adjust the arguments of the `\sisetup` instruction in order to achieve a more compact "look" of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class 
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
]\begin{table}
\sisetup{input-symbols = (), group-digits=false, 
         table-align-text-post = false}
\centering
\caption{Contemporaneous regression results\strut}\label{ContReg}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{S[table-format=-1.7]} @{}}
\toprule
 & {Delta} & {Delta} & {Delta} \\
\midrule
Intercept       & 0.0001       & -0.0004*    & 0.0001        \\
                & (0.0001)     & (0.0002)    & (0.0001)      \\
FF              & 0.1234**     & 0.4567*     & -0.1237       \\
                & (0.3255)     & (0.2354)    & (0.2134)      \\
FG              & 0.1246***    & -0.6678     & 0.7788***     \\
                & (0.1256)     & (0.3545)    & (0.4575)      \\
\midrule
$R^2$           & 0.5113       & 0.1150      & 0.5135        \\
Adj.\ $R^2$     & 0.4101       & 0.2124      & 0.9117        \\
Num.\ obs.      & {3888}       & {3780}      & {3394}        \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize$^{***}p<0.01$; $^{**}p<0.05$; $^{*}p<0.1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks much better now.